# Recent ChromeDriver Update seems to have broken the Actions class methods

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

This is a normal actions class sendkeys method wherein 4 days ago in the previous Chrome Browser and Chrome Driver it was working fine.Recent updates in ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser seems to be breaking the actions class now.

```
Actions action = new Actions(getDriver());
action.sendKeys(WebElement,"value").build().perform();
```

I am getting below error for the same script which was working previously. Can someone please advise if they are facing the same issue.

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: 
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.85)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'C02ZJ39SLVDM', ip: '10.0.0.32', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '1.8.0_261'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 90.0.4430.85, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da..., userDataDir: /var/folders/s9/763mfj75725...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:55488}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 6984e1ef17c9e96a15990830d711bc70

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.perform(RemoteWebDriver.java:618)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$BuiltAction.perform(Actions.java:639)
```